# Find all users with specific Roles in Entrust for Laravel 5

Tags: laravel, roles

I have used Entrust for Laravel 5, and I am creating a page in the admin where it displays all the users with 'customers' role. From the documentation, I know how to get a user's role but what I want is to get all the users that has the same roles.

Comment: for example, customer has relations with role than should reverse relations define role with customers, so that can help to get all users by roles.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe Entrust sets up the user/roles relationships for you so you'd just do the same thing you would normally do without Entrust.

```
$customers = User::whereHas('roles', function($query)
{
    $query->where('name', 'customer');
})->get();
```